# tf Lookup extrapolation into the past and future

Tags: ros-melodic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Code

```
listener = tf.TransformListener()
        listener.waitForTransform(self.robot_link, target_link, rospy.Time(), rospy.Duration(0.2)) 
        (trans, rot) = self.listener.lookupTransform(\
               self.robot_link, target_link, rospy.Time(0))
```

I added the listener . However, the error still exists.

```
listener = tf.TransformListener()
        # listener.waitForTransform(self.robot_link, target_link, rospy.Time(), rospy.Duration(0.2)) 
        # (trans, rot) = self.listener.lookupTransform(\
        #         self.robot_link, target_link, rospy.Time(0))

[ERROR] [1576884188.584635]: Error processing request: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1576884160.863920689 but the earliest data is at time 1576884184.773631096, when looking up transform from frame [tool/flashlight_pickup_link] to frame [base_link]
```

If I change my code to

```
now = rospy.Time.now()
listener.waitForTransform(self.robot_link, target_link, now, rospy.Duration(4.0))
(trans,rot) = listener.lookupTransform(self.robot_link, target_link, now)
```

The error will be

```
Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1576884523.732362032 but the latest data is at time 1576884500.023826838
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340479/tf-lookup-extrapolation-into-the-past-and-future/) by [Chao Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/50395/chao-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2019-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) on 2019-12-21**:
Try rospy.Duration(1). Also in first case in waitfortransform you gave self.robot_link, but in lookuptranform you used;\self.robot_link. change both to be same

**Comment by [Chao Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/50395/chao-chen/) on 2019-12-21**:
\self.robot_link is to swap the line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved. You need to synchronize the time on your laptop with the platform you are using.

---

Originally posted by [Chao Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/50395/chao-chen/) with karma: 56 on 2020-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0